# Pass JSON to aspx webmethod gives System.InvalidOperationException error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I am trying to learn jQuery and JSON by going through a few simple examples and this has me stumped.

I have a button that when clicked I would like to pass a JSON object through to a WebMethod, perform some string operations on it and return to the client side. However when I click the button nothing happens.

I have added a breakpoint to the webmethod, but that is never stepped into, it's like the webmethod is never called.

Inspecting the browser console I can see a `System.InvalidOperationException` error appears under the webmethod (full error message below).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Data to pass through to web method**

```
"id": "1", "name": "Zippy" 
"id": "2", "name": "George"
"id": "3", "name": "Bungle"
"id": "4", "name": "geoffrey"
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#SaveButton').click(function () {
    var jsonObj = [{ "id": "1", "name": "Zippy" }, { "id": "2", "name": "George" }, { "id": "3", "name": "Bungle" }, { "id": "4", "name": "geoffrey"}] 
    jsonObj = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
    SaveNewOrder(jsonObj);
});

function SaveNewOrder(jsonObj) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ColumnSetting.aspx/setrecord",
        data: jsonObj,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "html",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: OnError
    });
}
function OnSuccess(response) {
    $('#OutputDiv').html(response.d);
}

function OnError(response) {
    $('#OutputDiv').html(response.d);
}
```

**Web method and classes**

```
public class ListOfDestinationColumns
{
    public List<DestinationColumn> data { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationColumn
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}


[WebMethod]
public static string setrecord(string jsonObj)
{

    ListOfDestinationColumns Destinations = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<ListOfDestinationColumns>(jsonObj);

    string output = "Start<br/>";
    foreach (var item in Destinations.data)
    {
        output += string.Format("id: {0}, name: {1}<br />", item.id.ToString(), item.name);
    }
    output += "End";

    return output;
}
```

**Error message in browser console**

```
ExceptionType:"System.InvalidOperationException"
Message:"Type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' is not supported for deserialization of an array."
StackTrace:"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertListToObject(IList list, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, IList& convertedList)
↵   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)
↵   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)
↵   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)
↵   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)
↵   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
↵   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)
↵   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)"
```

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScriptSerializer does not deserialize the dictionary object especially if you have any complex types and dates.

You get the error as below,

> Type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[[System.String,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'
>   is not supported for deserialization of an array.

You can resolve this by using Newtonsoft.Json.

You can download Json.NET 9.0.1 (this version) from the link below.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Hope this helps!